# Populate two list with data

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

I currently have rest api call being done, with responseOne & responseTwo. I then add these response to a list casted to a wrapperclass. And this list is looped on to be displayed on vf page. Issue is that now I need 2 fields from the responseTwo to add these to my vf page. BOth response are linked with an ID with which data in the list can be linked. So from my responseTwo, i need number and Amount field to add this to my responseOne list to be displayed on vf page. I don't know how to achieve this based on adding the Amount to each specific data found in my responseOne.

So am trying to do looping in both datasets received.

```
for (Data.dataWrapper responseOne : listOne){
   for(Data.dataWrapper responseTwo : listTwo){
       if(responseOne.Id = responseTwo.id){
       /* i need to add the amount field from responseTwo to this specific  line of data at ID xxxx */
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad pattern on performance grounds; it is of `N*M` complexity because you must iterate over every item in `listTwo` for every item in `listOne`. This will negatively impact your CPU limits and the responsivity of your interface.

Your wrapper class should typically include all of the data that is required to display a line item. It's not clear why these don't; you have not included any of that context in your question. Here, the most I can recommend is to digest these items into  `Map<Id, Data.dataWrapper>` collections:

```
Map<Id, Data.dataWrapper> mapTwo = new Map<Id, Data.dataWrapper>();
for (Data.dataWrapper responseTwo : listTwo) {
    mapOne.put(responseOne.Id, responseTwo);
}
```

Then, you can loop over `listOne` and access its corresponding `listTwo` entry directly, through the Map keyed on `Id`. This avoid the multiplicative complexity, because you end up iterating through each list exactly once, and can simply do:

```
mapTwo.get(responseOne.Id); // yields corresponding responseTwo entity.
```

You then have the data elements you need and can digest them to meet the specific needs of your Visualforce page.